# JQuery search and copy DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div

```
<div id="s1">s1</div>
```

Can JQuery check the ID and create a copy of the div BUT with the 1 being changed to the next number?

Comment: which '1'? The id, content, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objective of this code is to create an ever advancing s index that uses a global `sIndex` variable that increments as each div is cloned. This allows for continual progressing numbers.

If you don't want the contents of the previous div when copying, try `clone(false)` instead.

```
var sIndex = 1;

function cloneSDiv() {
    var parent = $("#s" + sIndex);
    var clone = parent.clone();
    sIndex++;
    clone.attr("id", "s" + sIndex).insertAfter(parent);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.eventSelector').click(function() {
        cloneSDiv();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#s1").clone().attr("id", "s2").insertAfter("#s1");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `clone` function of jquery.

like this:

`var clone = $("#s1").clone();` However, the ID remains the same, But you can obviously change to that to whatever like: `clone.attr({"id":"s2"});`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without making the index global (which is all you asked for in the question). It acquires and clones the div, checks the id, and increments it to the next one. Wasn't sure how you planned on acquiring the div so if you are doing something else the important stuff is inside the each function.

```
$("div").each(function() {
    $(this).clone().attr("id", "s" + (parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace("s","")) + 1)).insertAfter("#s1");
    });
```